# Does an online/web accessible version of Dwarf Fortress exist?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Has anyone built a web interface for Dwarf Fortress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DFTerm2](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=50643.0) (usually used to play Dwarf Fortress running on another machine via a telnet client) has a browser interface that can be used to watch/play through flash. I haven't used it myself but I know quite a few people use DFTerm itself.

Sadly, DFTerm2 has now ceased development.

Configuring the browser interface for access is highly dependent on your own network setup and probably another question entirely.

Comment: Yay! Now I can play at work! Thank you for destroying my productivity!

Comment: screenshot link is dead